# High memory usage by process 'microsoft.vshub.server.httphostx64.exe' while using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, svc

The mentioned process has extremely high memory usage. Just after Visual Studio Update 3 I experienced the same issue and read that it was due to a memory leak within the application that hasn't yet been resolved. That time, the memory used sat at 2.5GB, this time, 7.7GB and it continues to climb even after rebooting. It hardly ever climbs this high even with two window instances of VS open.

The 'svcHost.exe' process too takes up a lot of resources and causes my pc to lag heavily (not visible in the screenshot below).

[image: CPU and RAM Utilization by VS2015 processes]

Even after killing the individual processes, they launch again with the same results. This issue has come up again after the recent Windows 10 update 'Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1607 for x64-based Systems (KB3194798)' though I doubt that its the cause.

I would appreciate any suggestions in order to resolve this issue.

If its any use, here's a list of the recent Windows 10 updates that have been installed:

- Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool for Windows 8, 8.1, 10 and Windows Server 2012, 2012 R2 x64 Edition - October 2016 (KB890830)
- Windows 10 Version 1607 for x64-based Systems (KB3194798)
- Windows 10 Version 1607 for x64-based Systems (KB3194496)

Comment: Are you starting VS in admin mode? do you have any extensions downloaded?

Comment: @SalahSh I don't start VS in admin. I do have a few extensions, Supercharger and CodeMaid to name a few. After disabling Supercharger, I found VS getting stuck on processes less frequently but memory use would still become excessive over time. A restart and 'clean' using CCleaner would resolve the 4-10GB of memory use issue and 'reset' it to its usual use. This would occur frequently when deploying a website locally or using the WCF test client.

Comment: This would be better on [su] because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

** The following may required you have administrator privileges on the box ***:

1. close all instances of Visual Studio 2015
2. Locate directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VsHub\
3. Rename VsHub to VsHub-Suppressed

Once the above has been performed, Visual Studio 2015 will start noticeably quicker.

Source: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1610160/microsoft-vshub-server-httphostx64-exe

Answer (score 2):

I just renamed the C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VsHub\1.0.0.0\Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe_

The Visual Studio 2015 raise and alert for a degradated installation... but works fine.

The other solution is to rename Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe and copy the Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHost.exe and change the name to the Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe

This is not the best way, but... its works.

Answer (score -1):

Program files --> Common files --> Microsoft shared --> rename VsHub folder to VsHub-Suppressed